# Get scrollTop to run more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How is it possible to get the smooth scroll working more than once (with JQuery:s scrollTop)?

```js
 var projectContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('projectContainer')[0];
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
 
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > position) {
    $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
        scrollTop: $(".projectContainer").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    projectContainer.style.background = "orange";
    $(window).bind("mousewheel", function() {
                $("html, body").stop();
            });
  } else {
      projectContainer.style.background = "white";
  }
  position = scroll;
});
```

```css
.top {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">Scroll</div>
<div class="projectContainer">hello</div>
```

I've tried this but it only works for the first time after running the script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not really clear what you're *trying* to do here - but add a `console.log` just before `.animate` and you'll see just how many (100s) of times it's running.

Comment: Also note there are many ways to start a scroll other than mousewheel - eg, but not limited to, grabbing the scroll bar handler with left mouse, clicking on the scroll bar away from the handler, pressing space, pressing cursor down, pressing page down

Comment: As alternative you can use this new css effect: html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }. Than you don't need the animation.